# HLOOKUP/MATCH combination returning incorrect value

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to perform a lookup in a table I've created using HLOOKUP to find my column, and MATCH to give me the correct row, which should result in the correct value being posted in my cell.

This is largely the case, however, certain values I'm looking up within the HLOOKUP are producing incorrect results. Specifically they're pulling from on column over.

Here's a smaller version of my table.

```
--------|CHS     |DDR     |MWD     |MTR     |RSS     |SUS     |WRL     |WPS     |
UAED    |3067110 |3067100 |3067112 |3067102 |3067104 |3067118 |3067116 |3067114 |
MOWD    |3075110 |3075100 |3075112 |3075102 |3075104 |3075118 |3075116  3075114 |
```

My formula is as follows, apologies for the long table references, I'm looking up a table in another file.

```
=HLOOKUP(S4003,'[UAT_EXT_MatTypes.xlsx]Plant-PL-PrftCntr'!$A$1:$I$72,MATCH(C4003,'[UAT_EXT_MatTypes.xlsx]Plant-PL-PrftCntr'!$A$1:$A$72,0))
```

S4003 and C4003 are the two values I'm using within my destination table to find the appropriate value in my lookup table. S#### refers to a product line (such as WRL or RSS), while C#### refers to a plant.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I pull a WPS product or an MWD tool, it will pull from the SUS and MTR fields respectively. This does not occur with any other values

For context on how these numbers are derived, the first 4 digits are derived from the plant, while the last 3 are derived by product line.

If anyone has any suggestions as to why this isn't working and how I can fix it, or any alternatives, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: use the fourth criterion in you HLOOKUP.  After the MATCH() put `,FALSE`

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I forgot this. Thank you so much.